# queryset working in the shell but not in the form

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I try to achieve a queryform allowing user to find a specific ads, I spent some times in the shell so I could write the function in the views.py but something is wrong as I don't get any results in my template.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from user.models import User

class Ads(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False) #I added an object called 'apple'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Offer(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    ads = models.ManyToManyField(Ads)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

forms.py

```
class SendOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    courses = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('ads', 'content')
        labels = {
            'content': _("write your ads here"),
            'ads': _("ads-number"), # TODO the label does'nt show up in the template
        }

class QueryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ads = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Course.objects.all(), required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QueryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].required = False
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = ('ads', 'content')
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    try:
        logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    except:
        pass
    if request.method=='GET':
        form = QueryForm(request.GET)
        results = None
        if form.is_valid():
            query_content = request.GET.get('id_content')
            if query_content:
                results = Offer.objects.filter(content__contains=query_content)
    else:
        form = QueryForm()
    return render(request, 'offers/search.html', locals())
```

template

```
    <form id="login_form" method='GET' action="{% url "search" %}"> 
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="chercher" />
            </p>        
    </form>
```

search.html

```
{% if results %}
{% for result in results %}
    <div class="result">
        <p>{{ result.content }}</p>
        <p>{{ result.cours.name }}</p>
    </div>

{% empty %}

    <p>No ads, sorry</p>  <!--TODO this is always showing up -->

{% endfor %}
{% elif results == None %}
<p>No ads, sorry</p>
{% endif %}
```

And finally, here is the query that I wrote in the shell

```
Offer.objects.filter(content__contains='apple')
[<Offer: a>, <Offer: a>]
```

that's working here but

```
results = Offer.objects.filter(content__contains='apple')
result = result[0]
result
<Offer: a>     # the user is called 'a', I was a bit lazy to create a real exemple of user ^^

res.content
'I'm an ads called apple'
res.ads
<django.db.models.fields.related.create_many_related_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7fdf5231deb8>
res.ads.name
print(res.ads.name)
None
```

Normally, I could see the content when I search for 'apple' but nothing appears in my template. Plus, I can see that I'm not even able to get the name of the ads. According to the admin, it's not None, it's apple. I take care of writting the following code to save the objects of the m2m relationship :

```
    if offerform.is_valid():        
        sent = True
        offer = offerform.save(commit=False)
        offer.publisher = User.objects.get(id=logged_user.id)
        offer.save()
        offerform.save_m2m()
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `locals()` to return context to the template. In your case, your `form.is_valid()` might be `False`, then the `results` stays as `None`. Also, if other people tries to read your code, they couldn't figure out what's in your context unless they go through the whole view method.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why do you use `GET` method for your form. Usually `POST` is the way to go.

Comment: I changed it with render(request, 'offers/search.html', {'form': form, 'results': results}) but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Can you print/debug and see if the `results` is empty or not? Your `results` could be `None`.

Comment: I changed the request method to POST and I assigned results in the beginning of the function

Comment: + 1000 for not using locals(). Add some print statement in your view. If form.is_valid() print "valid form".... else print form.errors ....

Comment: print query_content as well just in case

Comment: Ok guys, the error was the field name, instead of query_content = request.GET.get('id_content'), I have to write query_content = request.GET.get('content'). Thank you for your help guys :)